# Shuffle column in Excel but ea. value appears equal amount of times

Tags: excel, shuffle

I need to shuffle a column and make sure each value appears equal amounts of time.

I.e.

```
Bob          Joan
Clara        Bob
Joan         Ronald
Ronald       Clara
```

I tried `=SORTBY(B2:B65,RANDARRAY(ROWS(B2:B65)))` but this does not do what I need.

Edit:

These names are currently alphabetized but they need to be randomized and they can't appear immediately after each other, too. So i.e.

```
Clara
Clara 
Bob 
Ronald 
Joan 
Ronald 
Bob 
Joan
```

… would not be ok either.

Comment: does equal amount of time mean once each?

Comment: Oh it means that Joan can't appear twice, i.e., if the other names don't appear twice too. 

Apologies for the funky wording.

Comment: But what if you only want 15 results with a list of 12 names?

Comment: In this dataset this is not the case. The issue is that they are alphabitized and defeat the purpose of needing to randomize them by where names don't appear immediately after each other too. 

So i.e. 

Clara
Clara
Bob
Ronald
Joan
Ronald
Bob
Joan

Would also not be ok.

Comment: So you want to randomize the whole list then duplicate another random list below that one so the whole list is used before duplicates happen?

Comment: Does the original column(B2:B65) have duplicate names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will randomize the list.  It will use the whole list before creating dups. so no matter how many in the output list there will be as even a distribution as possible depending on the ratio of output names vs the input list.

```
=LET(rng,B2:B5,
    rw,ROWS(rng),
    num,E2,
    clm,ROUNDUP(num/rw,0),
    TAKE(INDEX(rng,UNIQUE(TOCOL(RANDARRAY(10*rw,clm,1,rw,TRUE)+SEQUENCE(,clm)/10,,TRUE))),num))
```

[image]

One note:  There is no guarantee that the last name of the preceding random group will not be the first of the next random group and as such they may be one right after the other.

[image]

But the more names in the list the less likely this will happen.